# Obter contador de objetos associados com Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Meu modelo **Projeto** tem *n* **Peças** (que também é um modelo). Eu quero adicionar uma função ou *lazy property* para saber quantas peças estão associadas a um determinado projeto.

Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu modelo use

```
class Projeto extends Model
{

    public function pecas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Peca');
    }
}
```

E para saber a quantidade use

```
$count = App\Projeto::find(1)->pecas->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu modelo deve estar assim.

```
class Projeto extends Model
{

    public function pecas()
    {
        # Veja mais detalhes no manual
        # http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
        return $this->hasMany('App\Peca');
    }
}

class Peca extends Model
{

    public function projetos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Projeto');
    }
}
```

adicione um novo method para poder ser reutilizado assim

```
class Projeto extends Model
{

    // ...

    # Exibir o total de peças, veja mais no manual
    # http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes
    public function scopeTotalPecas()
    {
        return $this->pecas()->count();
    }
}
```

em seu controller use

```
# ...
$total = Projeto::find(1)->totalPecas();
# ...
```